Why can't my .NET app see a network share when run from Task Scheduler?
I have an executable written in C# that looks in I:\contracts, which is a network share.  If I run it manually in PowerShell it works as expected.  However, if I set it up as a task in Task Scheduler, it can't see that network share.
I'm running the task as my own user.
Is there something special I need to do in the task so that it can see the share?

The following may be of interest: https://superuser.com/questions/640962/why-cant-a-task-scheduler-job-access-a-mapped-network-drive.

Try searching for windows task scheduler access mapped network drive

The following may be of interest: Connect to network drive with user name and password and How To Access Network Drive Using C#
